# Lumen shows blank page instead of showing an error on blade

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I came across with interesting problem,

I am using lumen on my windows localhost, the problem is while I write incorrect code or syntax error in my view/blade, lumen shows blank page instead of error. However, in controller or another page I am able to debug my code, It shows error.

Error debugging is open in php.ini.

APP_DEBUG=true in my project.

I have tried to fresh install, still same.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? Facing the same issue.

Comment: No. I gave up and switched to Laravel because I encountered some errors like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file , method `render`

e.g. make something like this:

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    if (env('APP_DEBUG')) {
        dd($exception);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

or you can grab it as it is instanceof `Illuminate\View\ViewException`

Comment: Thanks! I changed the file and now I'm able so fix the real problem.