# Can't send mail with Lumen framework and no error appears

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, swiftmailer, laravel-9

Since yesterday I have had problems sending emails with Lumen. I think I have followed all the steps in the documentation correctly, but unfortunately I cannot send anything. Moreover, no error is displayed (I have activated `APP_DEBUG=true`), and I am sure that the credentials of the smtp server are correct. I also did `composer require illuminate/mail`.

Here are my modifications in **bootstrap/app.php** (I have `$app->withFacades();` uncommented).
[image: Git changes on bootstrap/app.php]

Here is my build function content: `return $this->view('emails.mailTemplate', ['message' => $this->message]);`.

And the line of code that ask to send mail: `Mail::to("wewanthalflifethree@gmail.com")->send(new sendMail($destEmail, $subject, $message));`.

Did I do something wrong? :/

**Thx in advance for help!**

**EDIT: I just noticed something, the code stop working when I send the mail. If I add an echo after Mail::send, it will be appear on the page.**

Comment: It's not that GMail just outright trashes your email because your mail server doesn't have proper SPF, DKIM or DMARC authentication?

Comment: I was also thinking about that at first, but no it's not. I am using Zoho services for smtp server, it work well for all my others websites (such as cloud for example).

Comment: Ah, so you're using [the Zoho API](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/api/post-send-an-email.html), or SMTP server, to send an email. Yes, in that case they are probably responsible for your DNS records as well. Can you see in Zoho which mails you sent?

Comment: Not really the Zoho API, I'm using the usual host/port/username/password credentials. I do this for all my other scripts. https://prnt.sc/3BqXIYKETSz1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a problem with the Exceptions handler. By following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68691274/12680199) (which consists in adding a `dd` in the render function of `Handler.php`), I am now able to see what's going wrong.

So, here is the reason why my mail didn't send and why my page turned blank: `Object of class Illuminate\Mail\Message could not be converted to string (View: /home/serveur-web/api.sl-projects.com/resources/views/emails/mailTemplate.blade.php)`.

**The problem came from the fact that I was using the variable name `$message`, and this causes problems because it seems to be used in the class that handles the mails.** My problem was therefore solved by renaming this variable `$mailContent`.

I hope this will help other people. :D